# What are all the types of bending?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra, bending

What are all the types and sub-types of bending shown in the *Avatar: The Last Airbender* & *The Legend of Korra* universe? Here are the ones I can recall. Am I missing any?

1. **EARTHBENDING**

   a. Sandbending (Toph)

   b. Metalbending (Toph/Lin/Suyin)

   c. Lavabending (Ghazan/Bolin)

   d. Seismic Sense -"Seeing" via Earth vibrations (Toph/Lin)
2. **AIRBENDING**

   a. Unaided Flight (Zaheer)

   b. Spiritual Projection - "Ghost" Teleportation in the Physical World (Jinora)
3. **WATER/ICE BENDING**

   a. Bloodbending (Hama/Katara/Amon/Tarrlok)

   b. Spiritbending (Unalaq/Korra)

   c. Healing (Katara)

   d. Plantbending (Swamp Dwellers)
4. **FIREBENDING**

   a. Lightning Bending (Ozai/Iroh/Azula/Mako)

   b. Combustion Bending (Combustion Man/P'Li)
5. **ENERGYBENDING** (Aang/Korra/Lion Turtles)

Comment: Bending the energy within a person - look what Aang did to the Firelord at the end of _Avatar: The Last Airbender_ :)

Comment: @taTrifynor - I think they called that Spirit bending which I listed. That's what I was intending.

Comment: it's actually called energybending: http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Energybending But the wiki entry says "To bend another's energy, your own spirit must be unbendable, or you will be corrupted and destroyed." so those kinds of bending (spirit bending and energybending) seem to be quite related.

Comment: Maybe spoon bending?

Comment: @Adamant - There is no spoon in the Avatar matrix

Comment: Leg bending, arm bending, really anywhere with a movable joint.

Comment: I'd just like to say that "Seeing" and "Ghost Teleportation" are officially called Seismic Sense and Spiritual Projection, respectively. There's also Redirection, an advanced Fire-Bending technique inspired by Water-Benders, invented by Iroh and taught to Zuko, who then taught it to Aang. It's similar to, but not quite the same as, Lightning Bending. Other than that, you have all the different styles and even a few of the advanced techniques of bending.

Comment: This question sounds like the start of a new hit YouTube series, "Will It Bend?".

Comment: vacuum bending and tornado bending as air subcategories ? Zaheer tries to kill by creating a vacuum sometimes. And tornados seem to require a strong form of air bending. Ming-Hua's water artifical limb bending. Metal-spiderman like bending. Additionally there are 2 sub-categories of fire-bending, hate and life/passion based bending.

Comment: I really was hoping this was a Futurama question :(

Comment: Amon was not capable of energy bending. While he did block a persons energy through blood bending, he can't actually "bend" energy.

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/15267/4918 "What is the subset of Airbending?"

Comment: In the anime series, Zaheer mentions true flight as being achieved by an ancient Airbending master. Since Zaheer also received the power of Airbending before achieving true flight, it's likely this power over the *air* is a subset/possibility for only Airbenders, rather than simply an "other". Likewise Seismic Sense is only shown as an ability of a master Earthbender. I can't recall if spiritual project is shown by others or not but I think it's also only an Airbending thing. Healing likewise is a Waterbending subset; only Waterbenders are shown to use their bending for healing.

Comment: Is chi blocking considered a type of bending, or is chi blocking energybending?

Comment: Spacetime bending

Comment: @Unknown - I don't think chi blocking is a type of bending. On the 1st Season of *Korra*, the non-bending Equalists (who were anti-bending) used chi blocking against benders to help level the playing field.

Comment: Fart Bending (yes, really) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qz9UveDZyns

Comment: Is there any evidence that Jinora is using air bending to control her spiritual projection? Or is she simply just a person that's *really* spiritual and can thus project her consciousness outside her body? All we ever see her do to trigger it is meditate.

Comment: Tornado bending. Rain bending. You're only limited by your imagination.

Answer (score 3):

Other than your list, we did see fire sages performing some sort of healing or diagnostics on Korra.

Also, Aman was not an energy bender. Only avatars have that ability.

Comment: Aman certainly was an energy bender. Who took away Be Fong's bending abilities (and others)? Hint: Amon. And took Korra's water, earth, and fire bending abilities? Hint: Amon.

Comment: He did that through blood bending.

Comment: @iMerchant It's explained near the end of the first season that he does so through Water bending (Blood).

Comment: Amon was not an energy bender. Only Avatars have that ability. It is explained in Season 1 that Amon is using blood bending.

Comment: @John What does that comment add to the answer and the already extant comments describing the same thing?

Comment: We know that there are non-avatar energy benders. Aang met one..

Comment: @ForrestVenable: No, [chakras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakra) are not a form of bending.

Comment: @Kevin Aang learned energy bending from the lion turtles and used it like they did to take away element bending from people. He uses their exact same technique, adjusted solely for his smaller size.

Comment: I'd compare Amon's advanced blood bending *technique* (shutting off chakras) to an advanced earth bending technique (seismic sense), rather than them being disciplines unto themselves.

Comment: Amon was a bender bender. He bent benders.